# Automatic VPN Creation (Preferrably with VBScript)

Tags: vpn, pptp

I'm looking for a way to create a VPN connection automatically.

The connection should requires a Smartcard, use PPTP and disable using the remote default gateway.
So far all I could find was CMAK (Which does works but forces sort of a welcome window before the actual connection) and key emulation with VBScript (.SendKey).
The plan is to implement it within an HTA file, along with some other installations that are already set.

So far everything is written with VB, but if there isn't a solution there I could use anything else that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the answer...
Apparently all VPNs are located in the rasphone.ras file at "C:\Users\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk", which you can modify with Notepad, it's not encrypted or anything.
I simply use the script to paste a pre-saved VPN settings list, then all you have to do is refresh (F5) the Network Connections page.

Comment: Would love to know how to create a desktop shortcut to that VPN with the same script though...

Comment: You can just make a script in your language of choice that runs the command: rasdial.exe "VPN Connection Name" username password